# clear session on every first visit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, session

I have a facebook application which is session based. i am having bad behaviour as follows: if the user is using the app then logs out from facebook and some other user logs in to facebook and logs in the app they see the user data who just logged out.

Essentially I d like to clear the session every time visitor hits the first page.

I have a HomeController which extends BaseController in base controller i check if the user has a session.

where should i put Session.clear() in order to prevent user to access old user session?

on

```
HomeController{
   [authorize for facebook]
   indexAction{
      redirect to home action
   }

}
```

my concern is that when indexaction is invoked Before that base controller will be invoked and i will get a infinite loop.

Note: I m using a UserCookie which i store the user id and expiration of the cookie within.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to check if Facebook user ID matches data in session state. The easiest would be to put something like `Session["FBID"]=facebookId` and than check on every request if current facebookId matches `Session["FBID"], if not - clear session (irrespective of current location).

Comment: yes, i thought about that, i was seeking an easy answer. such as clearing the session at an entry point etc.

Comment: @DarthVader: It doesn't get much easier than comparing new facebook data to data in session.